# How to build a static library from Ada source that's callable from C++ code?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, ada

I need to build a static library with a bunch of code written in Ada that can be called from code written in C/C++.

I've searched through internet and got some knowledge about `gnatmake`, `gnatbind` and `gnatlink`, but still can't get the job done correctly.

Also, I've read there are tools that relies upon some kind of project file.
I'm not interested in those, I just need a bunch of commands to write in a `Makefile`.

Comment: It may not be that simple. The Ada code must be written to interface with C++ code. Not just any Ada code can interface with C++ code. What must be done, even after the Ada code is made to interface with C++ code is somewhat compiler dependent. Which Ada compiler are you using?

Comment: The question mentions gnatmake etc, so there’s a good chance it’s GCC.

Comment: @Simon Wright: Exactly.
The Ada code is nothing fancy, so I didn't encoutered any problem binding it. Althought the calling code is written in C++, I added a pure C layer in order to make the whole process easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer assumes you’re using the GCC toolchain.

The big hurdle is that Ada code needs elaboration (roughly, the equivalent of calling file-level constructors in C++). *gnatbind* is the tool that does this, and you use the flag `-L`:

```
-Lxyz     Library build: adainit/final renamed to xyzinit/final, implies -n
[...]
-n        No Ada main program (foreign main routine)
```

As an example, consider Ada source `foo.ads`,

```
package Foo is
   procedure Impl
   with
     Convention => C,
     Export,
     External_Name => "foo";
end Foo;
```

or, if using Ada prior to Ada2012,

```
package Foo is
   procedure Impl;
   pragma Export (Convention => C, Entity => Impl, External_Name => "foo");
end Foo;
```

and `foo.adb`,

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
package body Foo is
   procedure Impl is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("I am foo");
   end Impl;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("foo is elaborated");
end Foo;
```

and a similar pair of files `bar.ads`, `bar.adb` (`s/foo/bar/g` throughout).

Compile these:

```
gnatmake foo bar
```

Bind:

```
gnatbind -Lck -o ck.adb foo.ali bar.ali
```

(this will actually generate `ck.ads` as well as the named `ck.adb`; these are the code that does the elaboration).

Compile the elaboration code:

```
gnatmake ck.adb
```

Generate the library:

```
ar cr libck.a ck.o foo.o bar.o
```

and you’re nearly ready to roll.

The C main program might look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ckinit(void);
void ckfinal(void);
void foo(void);
void bar(void);

int main()
{
  ckinit();
  printf("calling foo:\n");
  foo();
  printf("calling bar:\n");
  bar();
  ckfinal();
  return 0;
}
```

(your main is in C++, so you’ll need `extern "C" {`..., of course).

You’d think that

```
gcc main.c libck.a
```

would do the trick. However, `libck` calls in the Ada runtime. Here (macOS), that means I say

```
gcc main.c libck.a /opt/gnat-gpl-2016/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/4.9.4/adalib/libgnat.a
```

(you can find that path using `gcc --print-libgcc-file-name`)

The resulting executable runs:

```
$ ./a.out
bar is elaborated
foo is elaborated
calling foo:
I am foo
calling bar:
I am bar
```

Comment: Just a question.
Is the following:
   procedure Impl
   with
     Convention => C,
     Export,
     External_Name => "foo";
Equivalent to:
procedure Impl;
pragma EXPORT (CONVENTION    => C,
                 ENTITY        => Impl,
                 EXTERNAL_NAME => "impl_c");

Comment: Yes; it’s the Ada2012 version, with aspects. But of course that would be `EXTERNAL_NAME => "foo"`, not `"impl_c"`.

Comment: Thank you, @SimonWright, extremely helpful.  I relied on your guidance heavily in the "cpp-main-big" subdirectory of the following GitHub project, which is successfully building on Travis CI:  https://github.com/dksmiffs/gnatmake-examples

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for you great help!
Actually, it worked with the following Makefile:

```
ada_libs := -lgnat -lgnarl

cpp_src := ...
ada_src := ...

library.so : $(cpp_src:.cc=.o) adalib.a
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(ada_libs)

$(cpp_src:.cc=.o) : %.o : %.cc
    g++ -c -o $@ $<

$(cpp_src:.cc=.d) : %.d : %.cc
    g++ -MM -MF $@ $^

$(addprefix objects/,$(ada_src:.adb=.o)) : objects/%.o : %.adb
    gnatmake -c -D objects $^

adabind.adb : $(addprefix objects/,$(ada_src:.adb=.o))
    gnatbind -n -o $@ $(^:.o=.ali)

adabind.ali : adabind.adb
    gnatmake -c -D objects $^

adalib.a : adabind.ali
    ar cur $@ $(^:.ali=.o) objects/*.o

include $(cpp_src:.cc=.d)
```

Besides this, I had to declare my function as extern "C" in my C++ file.

Thank you a lot, I was almost there but missed to include the ada runtime libraries (-lgnat -lgnarl) while linking.

Comment: If you’re going to create a shared library (`library.so`), you might want to compile the Ada with `-fpic` (or whatever your system needs). _gnatmake_ appears to take `-fpic` here ...

Comment: @Simon Wright: Indeed. I've omitted a bunch of switches (-fPIC among them), some of them I keep copying form a makefile to another without even knowing its meaning. :) Thanks for the explanation of this one.