# Why does this Ada Memory Data Export Code not work?

Tags: ada

I am new to Ada so it is a very basic question. I watched this Ada Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szh8eILpPEw&index=17&list=PLkoa8uxigENkneyEEeDWVPgpMhPc9IJ7o

In minute 5:11 theres a Code to Export Ada Memory Objects to a C Code. The Code doenst work for a reason. Is there something missing in the gap [...] in the C Code?
The Ada Code at the top is an .ads right?

Here is the Code:

```
ADACODE
with Interfaces.C
package ALib is
     The_Length : constant Interfaces.C.size_t := 80 with
              Convention      => C,
              Export          => True,
              External_Name   => "theLength":
end ALib;

CCODE
#include <stdio.h>
extern size_t theLength;
[ ... ]
printf("%d\n", theLength);
```

I'm using GPS

Comment: Hello, you should add the code in your question directly, instead of the mere link to youtube video. That being said, the problem is likely in the way you link your c file (because for it to work, you have to link with the ada file). Maybe add in your question the error you're getting, or anything that makes you say it doesn't work.

Comment: There is indeed something missing; I think it’s been left out of the video, a scan of this and the preceding video doesn’t show an example C main program. You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873379/40851) helpful, though it’s not really beginner-level. Interesting to know whether you get an answer to your comment on the video.